# How do you select what json info you serialize with jquery?

Tags: jquery, json, serialization

If my jquery serialization is posting the following:

```
{"PurchaseOrders":[{"Id":"8a4c70a63db7b320013dc35247960095","Version":124,"Context":{"RealmId":"1","CustomerId":"111","ProjectId":"2222","Operation":null}
```

How do I exclude the

```
{"PurchaseOrders":[
```

From my post, while still submitting everything it contains?

I'm currently using this script for my serialization:
https://github.com/tlowrimore/jquery.serialize-object/blob/master/jquery.serialize-object.js

```
(function($) {
    var methods = {
        setValue: function(path, value, obj) {
            if(path.length) {
                var attr = path.shift();
                if(attr) {
                    obj[attr] = methods.setValue(path, value, obj[attr] || {});
                    return obj;
                } else {
                    if(obj.push) {
                        obj.push(value);
                        return obj;
                    } else {
                        return [value];
                    }
                }
            } else {
                return value;
            }
        }
    };

    $.fn.serializeObject2 = function() {
        var obj     = {},
            params  = this.serializeArray(),
            path    = null;

        $.each(params, function() {
            path = this.name.replace(/\]/g, "").split(/\[/);
            methods.setValue(path, this.value, obj);
        });

        return obj;
    };
})(jQuery);

$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#btn-add-po-submit").click(function(e) {

        e.preventDefault();

        var formData = $("#form-add-po").serializeObject2();
        var url = $("#form-add-po").attr("action");

        console.log(url);

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: "application/json",
            url: url,
            dataType: 'json',
            data: JSON.stringify(formData),
            error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.error(textStatus);
            },
            success : function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                console.log(textStatus);

            }
        });
        /*$('#result').text(JSON.stringify($('form').serializeObject()));
        return false;*/
    });
```

Comment: Suppose that `json` is the full object. Can't you just pass `json['PurchaseOrders']`?

Comment: Where would that be passed in the above js?

Comment: `data: JSON.stringify(formData['PurchaseOrders']),`

Answer (score 0):

The JSON object should be apart of a variable somewher. If it's apart of `var obj` then you can get the array of PurchaseOrders by using `obj['PurchaseOrders']` or `obj.PurchaseOrders`.

Comment: sorry i'm a bit of a noob... where would that go in the following code? https://github.com/tlowrimore/jquery.serialize-object/blob/master/jquery.serialize-object.js

Comment: @beng You're trying to modify this jQuery plugin? Or are you using that jQuery plugin in your project?

Comment: I'm using that jQuery plugin in my project

Comment: @beng Can you edit your post with the code from your project where you are using that jQuery plugin?

Comment: sure thing, added it to the original post

Comment: @beng I'm assuming the `formData` has the data you're trying to limit. Just do `formData['PurchaseOrders']` resulting in something like `data: JSON.stringify(formData['PurchaseOrders'])` within your AJAX function.